# Updated Pandas 1.3 rule of thumb for RAM to dataset size ratio

Tags: pandas

The [2017 Pandas rule of thumb](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/) by the creator of Pandas was "have 5 to 10 times as much RAM as the size of your dataset".

The 5-10x rule of thumb was for pre-1.0 version of Pandas.

Is this rule of thumb still the same for Pandas 1.3?

Please provide links or descriptions to changes that have been made to Pandas that make it more memory efficient.  This isn't an opinion question - the original rule of thumb came from the creator of Pandas.

Edit: Here is [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zoPmQ6J1aE&ab_channel=Coiled) that talks about the new string dtype in Pandas 1.3 and shows how to quantify memory savings.  Some commenters are making it seem like this question is impossible to answer, but these improvements can be quantified.

Comment: I still think this question is far too broad. The premise is what amount of memory do I need to _analyze_ my data, and _analyze_ is just far too all-encompassing. Do you need to tabulate some simple group totals or derive a few new numeric columns -- you probably don't need that much more than the data. But do you need to do some complex merges, or operations that are done with broadcasting? Then you might hope to have 20x the memory for some of these intermediate steps, where the alternative of iteration, while more memory efficient, could take days or weeks to run.

Comment: @ALollz - looking for a rule of thumb, not a hard & fast rule.  It's what generally works, not what always works.  If it was possible to create a rule of thumb in 2017, I'd argue it's still possible now.  A rule of thumb is great for sizing nodes for analyses (e.g. I have 10GB of data, what memory size should I target when running a computation in the cloud).  Without a rule of thumb, users are grasping at straws.

Comment: @JohnE - updated a question with a link to a video that shows how to quantify memory savings with the new Pandas 1.3 string dtype.  There are objective ways to quantify memory usage over Pandas versions and see how things have improved.  A rule of thumb is a "a broadly accurate guide or principle, based on experience or practice rather than theory", which is what Wes gave in his article.  It seems like you're conflating "rule of thumb" with "rigorous answer".  Yes, I want a "non-rigorous and vague (though expert) opinion" aka a rule of thumb.  That's what is stated in the question.

Comment: Btw, I think you are probably taking Wes's rule of thumb too literally. As I read what he said, I think his point was more that 5x to 10x is very inefficient compared to other languages and there is room for improvement. Regardless, you'd probably have better luck with this question in other forums than SO, though I'm certainly interested if anyone is able to answer this question. (I suspect a possible answer here would be to use %memit with both new and old versions of pandas and see if there is any noticeable difference.  I may even try that myself if I have enough time in the next day or so

Comment: @JohnE - ya, in my opinion good idea. Some ideas - compare some merge, aggregation, arithmatic, loop in apply , string and datetime operations should be interesting in my opinion.